# AWS CLI S3 - moving all files in a bucket into a single directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have an S3 bucket with paths such as:

```
s3://mybucket/data/2017-01-01/raw/file_file1.txt
s3://mybucket/data/2017-01-01/raw/file_file2.txt
s3://mybucket/data/2017-01-01/filtered/file_file3.txt
s3://mybucket/data/2017-02-01/edited/file_file4.txt
```

Is there a way to move all files at the end of the directories (they all start with `file_`) into:

```
s3://mybucket/data/
```

with a single command?

Answer (score 1):

Recursively copying S3 objects to another bucket

When passed with the parameter `--recursive`, the following `cp` command recursively copies all objects under a specified bucket to another bucket while excluding some objects by using an `--exclude` parameter. In this example, the bucket `mybucket` has the objects `test1.txt` and `another/test1.txt`:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/ s3://mybucket2/ --recursive --exclude "mybucket/another/*"
```

Output:

```
copy: s3://mybucket/test1.txt to s3://mybucket2/test1.txt
```

You can combine `--exclude` and `--include` options to copy only objects that match a pattern, excluding all others:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/logs/ s3://mybucket2/logs/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.log"
```

Output:

```
copy: s3://mybucket/test/test.log to s3://mybucket2/test/test.log
copy: s3://mybucket/test3.log to s3://mybucket2/test3.log
```

In your case it will be:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/data/ s3://mybucket/data/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "file_*.txt"
```

Source: [AWS CLI `cp` command documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to do

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/data/ s3://mybucket/data/ --recursive --include "file_file*.txt"
```

to copy it

Comment: Thank you for the response, but that gives an error. I don't think there is support for wildcards in the path name

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after I hit save, this should be more effective